Property of conditional expectation, independence, can the assumption be relaxed?
On Wikipedia they have this property:

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\mathcal{G}$, $\mathcal{H}$ are
independent, $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{H}$ and $Y$ is
independent of $\mathcal{G}$, then
$$E(E(XY|\mathcal{G})|\mathcal{H})=E(X)E(Y)=E(E(XY|\mathcal{H})|\mathcal{G}).$$

Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties
I am wondering if it holds also if we do not have the sentence "$X$ is independent of $\mathcal{H}$ and $Y$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$"?
The reason I think this is that $E(XY|\mathcal{G})$ is $\mathcal{G}$ -measurable. So $E(E(XY|\mathcal{G})|\mathcal{H})=E(E(XY|\mathcal{G}))$, since $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are independent. By the law of total expectation we have $E(E(XY|\mathcal{G}))=E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$, where we used independence of $X$ and $Y$ in the last step.
Did I overlook something?, or can we simplify the statement in the Wikipedia-article?

I think you are right.

Indeed, the assumptions that $X$ is independent of $\mathcal H$ and $Y$ is independent of $\mathcal G$ are not needed. As you pointed out, we only need the independence between $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$, and the independence between $X$ and $Y$.
